# Rotating One UIView Causes Another To Be Pushed OffScreen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, iad

I have a ViewController which contains a couple of UILabels, a UIImageView and an ADBannerView.  There are two relevant movements:  The UIImageView rotates based on the angle at which the user is holding their device, and the ADBannerView slides into view based on whether it has an iAD to display.

If the UIImageView is stationary, the ADBannerView slides into view correctly.  However, once the UIImageView starts rotating, the ADBannerView disappears.  AFAIK the two views are completely independent.

```
- (void) updateFloatingBar
{

    double angleToUpright = [self calculateAngleToUpright];
    double newAngle = angleToUpright - self.currentAngle;
    [self.FloatingBarImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newAngle*(CGFloat)(M_PI/180))];

}

- (void) hideAd
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Hidden");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.adBannerView cache:YES];
    self.adBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height + 50,50,320);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showAd
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Shown");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.compassADBannerView cache:YES];
    self.compassADBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.size.height - 50,50,320);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Again, the first method works correctly, it just also has the secondary effect of pushing offscreen the adBannerView placed by showAd:

Comment: Are you using constraints based layout? That might push the AdBannerView out. It also could be relevant to post the exact view layout you have...

Comment: The Views are instantiated from a storyboard.  These are the values they have when they are instantiated:  The ImageView has its Center X and Center Y aligned to SuperView, and the adBannerView has Leading Space and Trailing Space set to SuperView, and TopSpace set to superview 500.  Of course, that last value is changed when either of the second two methods are called.  Since they are both aligned to superview, I don't see how they could be interfering with each other.

Comment: You're right, @BobVork, it was something to do with constraints.  I turned off Autolayout, and set everything up with Struts and Springs and it all works perfectly.  I still don't know what the problem was, but at least it works now, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.